# In SciPy.IO.wavfile I am experiencing an issue with ndim of my data

Tags: python, io, scipy, waveform

I have a 1 dimensional array y, with 132300 entries.

```
print y.ndim
```

gives me 1.

Now, when I use    write('440saw2000.wav', '44100', 'y') I receive the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Matt\The Mathematics Of Digital Synthesizers\Scripts\filter.py", line 47, in <module>
write('440saw2000.wav', '44100', 'y')
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\wavfile.py", line 161, in write
if data.ndim == 1:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

How can I resolve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the string 'y' instead of the variable `y` as the data argument.

It should work like this:

```
write('440saw2000.wav', 44100, y) # without quotes around y and 44100
```

Comment: Thankyou very much. I am obviously very inexperienced!